# typo3 fe Login does not work

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I have a typo3 6.2 instance running with feLogin. 
Until yesterday the login works perfectly, since 2pm yesterday login is not possible anymore.

There haven't been any code changes.

What could be the issues?

The redirect works fine.

Thanks in advance

Comment: full hard-disk?

Comment: there still 17G left but maybe the hoster prevents the last 10% for not storing data

Comment: does BE-login work?

Comment: yes be-login works fine

Comment: storing data works fine as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check the logs
2. Check the TYPO3 configuration for `FE|loginSecurityLevel`
3. Check if rsaauth is installed when using `loginSecurityLevel = rsa`

Comment: 1.) system logs or typo3 logs?
2.) which is the right level?
3.) rsaauth is installed

Comment: 1. Both 2. Depends what you are using 3. If rsaauth is installed, it should be `rsa`

Comment: Is the current page in SSL? If yes, you can remove rsaauth. (It will be removed in v9 anyway)

Comment: is it has ssl. and what about the stored passwords?

Comment: are users able to login whith same credentials?

Comment: rsaauth does not change the passwords. It encrypts the password before sending and decrypts it before storing process (where it is salted and encrypted again). rsaauth is a tool to prevent sending clear text passwords, which is obsolete when using SSL.

Comment: I changed to normal and deaktivated the rsa extension. same issue not logged in.

Comment: did you delete cookies and browser-cache of the site?

Comment: @Felix check the browser-console during login.

Comment: I test it with opened console

Comment: I think typo3 fe login writes user not in session