# typo3 front end login disconnects the user immediately

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I have a typo3 6.2.31 website running.

I have the problem that the user is logged out immediately after the successful login.

A cockie is created, just as the session is written to the database.

What could be the reasons for an immediate logout?

thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [typo3 fe Login does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51493992/typo3-fe-login-does-not-work)

Comment: Should I add the new Input to the old question? I think its a new question, because Login Works fine but User is logged Off directly ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies are assigned to a domain. As secured connecteion are more and more important I have seen a lot of problems with the handling of `http` and `https`, which can not interchanged everywhere. maybe your session cookie gets set to http://your.domain as the server is behind a proxy which redirects any https call to the webserver which works only http. you might loose your cookie as it does not match the domain any longer.
The same goes for webserver handling multiple domains.

Have you set a unique and working cookie domain in the Install tool?

Hint: does your BE work as expected and are FE and BE on the same domain? Then compare settings for FE and BE cookies.

Comment: Settings are the same and FE and BE are one the same server